# string to array in php not possible while retieving from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

when i use this code

```
$a=array ( 'Q1' => 'gravity', 'Q2' => 'm*a',);
```

print_r($a);
output will be array

$a is an array

suppose `array ( 'Q1' => 'gravity', 'Q2' => 'm*a', )` is stored in a table column

when retrieved this column values and stored in a variable
then that variable is not an array

Comment: You can't store an array in a table column.

Comment: If you store a string in a database, you will retrieve a string. `"array ( 'Q1' => 'gravity', 'Q2' => 'm*a', )"` is a string. Have a look at [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) : you can store an array as a string, and then unserialize this string to retrieve your array.

Comment: Its indeed a string, not an array. You don't store arrays like that in a database and then convert them to real arrays on runtime. See the comment above about `serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

before you save in db try:

```
json_encode($a);
```

result is json string, You should save that string in database. 
Then when you get from db just json decode that string.

```
json_decode($string_from_database);
```

Comment: Use json_decode($string_from_database,TRUE); rather to get exact array instead of stdclass object.

Answer (score 0):

You can store array in to database using this one

```
$a=array ( 'Q1' => 'gravity', 'Q2' => 'm*a',);
$arrstr=mysql_escape_string(serialize($a));
```

Retrived by this function

```
$array= unserialize();
```

Comment: while retrieving,is_array($array) is false